# Kubuntu not booting on T420 after update

Tags: kubuntu

I was running Kubuntu 14 when i was told there is a new version available. I downloaded the update but the laptop wont boot past the Kubuntu logo. I am a rookie user. Please help.

Comment: Wich versions was that you downloaded?

Comment: What happens when you try Ctrl+Alt+F1?

Comment: It goes into BIOS. I have no problem with booting Kubuntu 14,  only when I upgrade to 16. it installs and everything but when I restart after installation a blue box shows up with ubuntu at top of boot order and the screen goes blank.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you everyone for your suggestions.I was finally able to overcome the problem and this is what I did:

I downloaded the update as usual and let it run it's course until it came to the part where it asked me if I wanted to delete the files from the old version before installing new ones. I clicked on "keep old files" and believe it or not I had no black screen or problem booting in. Everything works flawlessly. However, please do not ask me to explain how and why, I have no idea! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Does anything happen if you press e to edit the line at the grub boot screen, before the kubuntu logo, then add 'nomodeset' to the end of the line, and press alt+x or f10 to boot? Maybe your graphics chip is not supported out of the box by the newer one. This would possibly allow you to get in and install a graphics driver by using a basic graphics mode.

Comment: Thank you, Kyle H. I was able to boot into the new kernel eventually.

Comment: you're welcome! Happy to help, and glad you finally got your system up.